# Golang http.PostParam not showing all Cookies in the Response

Tags: http, go

I'm studying Golang and I'm trying to reach an endpoint (which I don't have control).

That's the code I wrote:

```
params := url.Values{}
params.Add("data[User][username]", <THE_USERNAME>)
params.Add("data[User][password]", <THE_PASSWORD>)
resp, _ := http.PostForm(<LOGIN_URL>, params)

fmt.Println(resp.Cookies())
```

The `Println` prints `[PHPSESSID=<ID>; Path=/; HttpOnly]`.

When doing the same request in Postman

```
POST /login HTTP/1.1
Host: <HOST>
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 399a42af-00f2-4340-b7fa-1ae1fa295b62

<PARAM_DATA>
```

I can see two cookies being set in the response, the `PHPSESSID` (which I guess is the same in Golang) and `au` (which is the token I need in order to authenticate against the server).

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong and why I cannot see the `au` Cookie when calling the endpoint using the Golang code.

Any guess?

Comment: When you try `curl` do you see the same thing as in postman or as in Go?

Comment: @mkopriva I do see.
For some reason I'm getting a lot of PHPSESSID from the server, but since I don't have control over the server, I'm just worried about the `au` cookie.

Comment: Sorry, I do see the same thing as in Postman. I can see the `Set-Cookie: au=<AUTH_TOKEN>; expires=Wed, 08-Aug-2018 21:55:25 GMT; path=/` when `curl` in verbose mode.

Comment: In Go if you do `log.Println(resp.Header["Set-Cookie"])` is the `au` there?

Comment: No, it only shows `2018/07/26 00:18:37 [PHPSESSID=<PHP_TOKEN>; path=/; HttpOnly]`.

Comment: I'm out of ideas in that case.

Comment: Are you sure that username and password are correct? Perhaps the login just doesn't succeed. Have you checked that the body is as expected?

Comment: I'm completely sure. Today I saw the `au` cookie doesn't have the `HttpOnly` field. This might be related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have an HTTP redirection (302 or 301).

Try this:

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "net/url"
)

func main() {
    params := url.Values{}
    params.Add("data[User][username]", "test")
    params.Add("data[User][password]", "test")

    client := &http.Client{
        CheckRedirect: func(req *http.Request, via []*http.Request) error {
            return http.ErrUseLastResponse
        },
    }
    resp, err := client.PostForm("http://example.com", params)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    log.Println(resp.Cookies())
}
```

In the overview of the net/http package [documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#pkg-overview) you have an example on how to control the redirection policy.

Good luck.